# android listview row with variable number of child views

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView and each row show a number of TextViews. Some rows contain 1 TextView, while others can contain any number of TextViews, each placed below the previous.

Is there any way to create a single layout file for this, instead of creating a layout file for each case (ie, 1 layout file for the 1 TextView, another for the rows with 2 TextViews, another for the row with 3 TextViews, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create TextView or inflate custom layout from the code

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to do this from code rather than inflating a resource? I've only ever inflated resources to create my layouts.

Comment: `TextView tv = new TextView(context);
//you can optionally create the layout params: 
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

container.addView(tv, params);`

also you can inflate the layout
`View view = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
container.addView(view);`

you can set ID for your view, etc.